# How to give folder permissions in Helm v4?

Tags: website, permissions, web-hosting, filezilla

I have a website, and I'm trying to give folder permissions with FTP Filezilla software, since I can't find this option in Helm web hosting portal.

CHMod seems to be a unrecognized command on FileZilla.

Does helm have an option to set write permissions to a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think you just can't using Helm web based interface. My hosting support had to manually set these permissions. I really don't like this Plesk and Helm stuff.